# iOS Device Simulator on Mac getting "crypto.randomUUID is not a function"

Tags: safari, ios-simulator

I'm not really understanding why I'm seeing this error `crypto.randomUUID is not a function` when viewing said web app on iOS Simulator's Safari, when simulating any of the devices (iPad, iPhone, etc).  I understand what the error means, I'm just surprised that randomUUID is not supported.   It works on any other desktop browser, including physical iPad and iPhone devices.  Is the simulator lacking something that I'm not understanding that needs configuration?  I assume the simulator should be faithful to the actual hardware.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No one has answered this yet and you've probably solved this on your own already.  Most of version 15 doesn't support crypto. IIRC versions 15.0 through 15.3 (maybe i think even to 5); Anything after that is fine. I say maybe because Apple doesn't state this anywhere as far as I'm aware. I've discovered this on my own through testing for work.

This hacky but you can get around this by adding a polyfill (I know it stings) I wouldn't expect Apple to remedy this any time soon because it feels like they gave up on Safari IMO.

Comment: I'm not following @Dave Maison. You say `iOS doesn't support crypto after iOS 15` but this works fine on a _physical_ device running iOS 16.  It just doesn't work when the device _simulated_ on macOS.

Comment: sorry, i misspoke. Most of version 15 doesn't support `crypto`. IIRC versions 15.0 through 15.3 (maybe i think even to 5); Anything after that is fine. I say _maybe_ because Apple doesn't state this anywhere as far as I'm aware. I've discovered this on my own through testing for work.

Comment: You know what? You're rigth @Dave Maison.  I tested again with the latest Xcode update and the simulator runs iOS 16.  And it does work there.  The simulator I was running before must have had one of those versions of iOS where it doesn't support it.  I should have checked before upgrading to report back here.  Anyhow, i'll edit your answer to reflect your latest comment and I'll accept it as the answer. thanks!

Comment: It can't be used with Safari 15.3 or older: https://caniuse.com/?search=crypto.randomUUID